# Failed to load file through getopt package in R

Tags: r, getopt

I am trying to use getopt package to open my file but the codes seem not working:

```
> library(getopt)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)

spec = matrix(c(
'help'   , 'h', 0, "character",
'input'  , 'i', 1, "file",
'output' , 'o', 1, "character"), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4)
opt = getopt(spec)
if(opt$input){
file <- read.table(args[1])
}
print(file)
```

I am trying to use command line to run the codes like:

```
Rscript --slave filename.R -i file.txt
```

The error information is: 
    Error in storage.mode(peek.optstring) <- mode : invalid value
    Calls: getopt ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch
    Execution halted
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the components, and if `-i filename.txt` is given then `opt$file` is what you use to access it.

A repaired version is

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(getopt)
spec <- matrix(c(
    'help'   , 'h', 0, "character",
    'input'  , 'i', 1, "character",
    'output' , 'o', 1, "character"),
    byrow=TRUE, ncol=4)
opt <- getopt(spec)

if ( !is.null(opt$input) ) {
    file <- read.table(opt$input)
}

print(file)
```

I used to use this package quite a bit, but these days I much prefer [docopt](https://cran.r-project.org/package=docopt) which is even easier to use and more featureful.

Answer (score 0):

In case others run into this same problem, I got the same error message

```
Error in getopt_options(object, args) : 
  Error in storage.mode(this.argument) <- mode : invalid value
Calls: parse_args -> parse_options -> getopt_options
```

My error turned out to be from accidentally misspelling my type argument:

```
make_option(c("--chr_len"), type = 'chaqracter', default = NULL, help = "file path: length of all chromosomes")
```

This error was resolved when I fixed the spelling

```
  make_option(c("--chr_len"), type = 'character', default = NULL, help = "file path: length of all chromosomes")
```